# Write a query to print the employee name and UIN in each line. If no UIN is present print NULL in its place. The order of output does not matter

Tags: mysql

There are two tables `EMPLOYEES` and `EMPLOYEE_PAN`. We have to print employee `NAME` from `EMPLOYEES` table and UIN from `EMPLOYEE_PAN` table. `ID` is in both the tables used as a primary key. If no `UIN` is present in `EMPLOYEE_PAN` table then we have to print `NULL` instead of `UIN`. `UIN` is an integer.

I have tried this code. I am facing an error in the case when statement part. I am facing a problem in case statements when `JOIN` is used in the query. Please let me know how to use `CASE` statement with `JOIN`.

```
SELECT UIN, NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE_PAN JOIN EMPLOYEES 
ON EMPLOYEES.ID = EMPLOYEE_PAN.ID 
CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_PAN.UIN != 0 THEN EMPLOYEE_PAN.UIN END ;
```

Comment: Use left join and remove the case statement

Comment: The order of output *should* matter!

Answer (score 3):

You need  left  join

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_PAN.UIN, EMPLOYEES.NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEES    
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_PAN  ON EMPLOYEES.ID = EMPLOYEE_PAN.ID
```

left join return null value for not matching keys

Answer (score -1):

Use a case statement in SELECT clause

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EMPLOYEE_PAN.UIN != 0 THEN EMPLOYEE_PAN.UIN ELSE "NULL" END AS UIN, NAME 
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE_PAN JOIN EMPLOYEES 
    ON EMPLOYEES.ID = EMPLOYEE_PAN.ID;
```

Note: I consider no UIN present in the table means UIN value is 0 (from your query )